# Using regex to announce function Parameters?

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-lab

I have a code with assigned functions. I want to call out the functions that don't have full parameters.

Examples – positive

```
uint8_t calculateCircumference(uint8_t radius, float* circumference);
```

Examples – negative

```
uint8_t calculateCircumference(uint8_t, float*);
```

I was working on this with Regex, 1st. to find the strings in the code that have the same pattern as a fucntion... which isn't working much:

```
import re
lineNum = 0
Parameters_group ='' 
Parameter_list= []
for element in codeStringlist:
   lineNum += 1
   pattern= re.compile(r'[ a-zA-Z_0-9]+\(([^\)]*)\)(\.[^\)]*\))?')
   matches= pattern.finditer(element)

   for match in matches:
     #Parameters_group += (match +',' )
     #Parameter_list.append(match.split(','))
     print('line:', lineNum, '\t', match.group())
```

result:

```
line: 6      0200 (Mi, 19 Mai 2021)

line: 33     CanAnalyserVersace(TreatmentUnit *tu)

line: 34     CanAnalyserVersace()

line: 42     void parsePublicDataUnit(int index, uint32_t data)

line: 49     void parsePublicDataDentist(int index, uint32_t data)

line: 58     void parsePublicDataTouch(int index, uint32_t data, bool isLocalEcho)

line: 67     void setTimerState(uint8_t id, uint32_t data)
```

I don't want something like the first result of the date included.

Answer (score 0):

So you need an expression that matches:

- the start of a line
- a sequence of one or two words (separated by space, with no trailing space), followed by
- an open parenthesis, followed by
- optional

  - a pair of words, the first optionally followed by '*'
  - optionally followed by "comma", "space" and repeat

  followed by
- a closed parenthesis

Traslating this into a regexp, condition by condition (squash it in one line to get the regexp):

```
^
 \w+( \w+)?
           \(
             (
              \w+[*]? \w+
                         (, \w+[*]? \w+)+
                                         )?
                                           \)
```

This will return the well-formed function headers.